# Deleting duplicates in a table based on a criteria only in SQL

Tags: sql, duplicates, sql-delete

Let's say I have a table with columns:

```
CustomerNumber
Lastname
Firstname
PurchaseDate
```

...and other columns that do not change anything in the question if they're not shown here.

In this table I could have many rows for the same customer with different purchase dates (I know, poorly designed... I'm only trying to fix an issue for reporting, not really trying to fix the root of the problem).

How, in SQL, can I keep one record per customer with the latest date, and delete the rest?  A `group by` doesn't seem to be working for my case

Comment: What is the primary key for this table?

Comment: it's not really a table used by the front end app...it's kind of a log - no PK

Comment: You want to actually delete or just select the records with the max PurchaseDate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me (on DB2):

```
 DELETE FROM my_table 
 WHERE (CustomerNumber, Lastname, Firstname, PurchaseDate) 
 NOT IN ( 
       SELECT CustomerNumber, Lastname, Firstname, MAX(PurchaseDate) 
       FROM my_table 
       GROUP BY CustomerNumber, Lastname, FirstName 
 )
```

Comment: it's a fox table and this worked as well...with some modifications. thanks a lot

Comment: Glad it helped. I'm not sure whether this is ANSI SQL or not, because the part before the NOT IN isn't a scalar value. What did you have to modify?

Answer (score 7):

```
;with a as
(
select row_number() over (partition by CustomerNumber, Lastname, Firstname order by PurchaseDate desc) rn
from <table>
)
delete from a where rn > 1
```

Comment: beat me, was just about to post a CTE version like this.

Comment: That's a good one. One nice thing about your version is that it'll pick only one record even if there are multiple lines on the latest purchase date.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CustomerNumber, Lastname, Firstname, MAX(PurchaseDate) LatestPurchaseDate
FROM Table
GROUP BY CustomerNumber, Lastname, Firstname
```

The MAX will select the highest (latest) date and show that date for each unique combination of the GROUP BY columns.

EDIT: I misunderstood that you wanted to delete records for all but the latest purchase date.

```
WITH Keep AS
(
    SELECT CustomerNumber, Lastname, Firstname, MAX(PurchaseDate) LatestPurchaseDate
    FROM Table
    GROUP BY CustomerNumber, Lastname, Firstname
)
DELETE FROM Table
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM Keep
    WHERE Table.CustomerNumber = Keep.CustomerNumber
    AND Table.Lastname = Keep.Lastname
    AND Table.Firstname = Keep.Firstname
    AND Table.PurchaseDate = Keep.LastPurchaseDate
)
```

Comment: I think you missed **"and delete the rest?"**

Comment: Try it; there will only be one row for each customer, as long as all the appearances of the customer have the same (CustomerNumber, Lastname, Firstname).

Comment: I know it will select the correct records, and exclude the rest, but I was interpreting the request to "delete" as an actual `DELETE` statement.

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood. Edited to add DELETE statement.